# Acid/basic chemicals that can be used without extraction hood?

Tags: anthropology, forensics, decomposition

I need to use some meat dissolvent for my thesis, I’m working in forensic anthropology, but in my university, we are not allowed to use those which might be extremely harmful (such as HF or HCl due to the fumes).

Friend of mine suggested me to use CaO and KOH, since you only need normal lab equipment. Do you have other suggestions that might come in handy?

Thank you! All the help I can get is really appreciated